# Get the self name with macros Openoffice

Tags: macros

I have a file foo.odt, inside that I want to write a macro. That macro will be output the name of the file in this case foo.odt. I trying to use ThisComponent.getUrl but that output the entire path/foo.odt I only want foo.odt

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I trying to use ThisComponent.getUrl but that output the entire path/foo.odt I only want foo.odt

Comment: If you havealready come so far, I would look into string manipulation functions and/or regular expression functions.